# javascript src on click without jquery

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript beginner.

```
function PlayPause() {
if (playing) {
    playing = false;
    v*****s.pause();
} else {
    playing = true;
    v*****s.play();
}
};
```

what I want is add a line which change the source of an image in my html code. do exist something like this

```
function PlayPause() {
if (playing) {
    playing = false;
    Vianeos.pause();
    src="img_1"
} else {
    playing = true;
    Vianeos.play();
    src="img_2"
}   
};
```

I hope that you understand what I mean.
if need to be more explicit just ask me 
:)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you would want to do this without JQuery? It saves you from writing a lot of useless code.

Comment: @JesseSchokker best to learn the basics of native js before moving onto using libraries

Comment: Alright. I've answered your question, if you would mind accepting it.

Comment: yes I have a reason to use javascript. it is a project for an exam with JS only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id to you image element in html :

```
<img src = "anything" id= "myImage" >
```

then update it from you function in javascript :

```
function PlayPause() {
var imageElement = document.getElementById("myImage");

if (playing) {
    playing = false;
    Vianeos.pause();
    imageElement.src="img_1"
} else {
    playing = true;
    Vianeos.play();
    imageElement.src="img_2"
}   
};
```

Comment: it is working thank you !

Answer (score 0):

var imgEle = document.getElementById("imgtag");
imgEle.src="anything";